# Tooltip on moderator view of flag counts is a lie

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, moderator-tools, tooltips

This is what I (a mod on Anime.SE) see on [my Anime.SE profile](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/1908/senshin):

[image]

It's weird that I have 197 "helpful flags" but only 28 "raised flags marked useful", per the tooltip on the parenthesized "(28)". Is the tooltip correct?

I happen to have 28 declined flags (3 regular, 25 comment) on Anime.SE, and I suspect this is not a coincidence. The tooltip should probably read "Total number of declined flags" or something.

Comment: Weird. I can see this happen on another user on a site I mod, but not all users have it, even if they have helpful flags.

Comment: So is the cake, but you don't see me - oh, who am I kidding, I'm still angry with GladOS...

Comment: @HDE226868: Pretty sure it's diamond-only or some such rubbish :P

Comment: @NathanTuggy I know it is (ah, the rubbish mods have to dig through); I'm just saying that it doesn't only appear on a mod's own profile, but on the profile of others, too - which makes it even a bit stranger.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tooltips shouldn't lie.

I've reprimanded this one - it feels bad and will stop doing it.

With you in the next build.